# d3 multiline chart animations

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building multiline charts - I am keen to improve this so it can handle multiple line data sets - and also animation/update features.

would be looking to separate the setup and update methods

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1408/

```
var selector = methods.el["selector"];

var padding = 5;


var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg:svg")
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "linechart")
  .attr("transform", "translate(30,30)");


var margin = {
    top: 35,
    right: 35,
    bottom: 35,
    left: 35
  },
  width = h - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = w - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y");

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, 315])

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.close);
  });


//mash arrays together to return max and min vals
var d = data[0].concat(data[1]);


x.domain(d3.extent(d, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain(d3.extent(d, function(d) {
  return d.close;
}));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Price ($)");

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data[0])
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr("d", line);

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data[1])
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr('stroke', 'blue')
  .attr("d", line);


function type(d) {
  d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3.js line chart animations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972884/d3-js-line-chart-animations)

Comment: No - its a different chart - in this instance it would be a case of looping through a dataset efficiently to handle more than two.